# Wordpress custom file upload in page

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using this code for PHP file upload (found directly on the wordpress page):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

upload.php

```
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
         || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
         || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
         || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                   "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

It always returns "invalid file" even when I know 100% it should work.

I've been looking around online and I think that WP cannot do enctype="multipart/form-data" so that's why it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a work around or any idea why this won't work?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

why not use WordPress built-in uploader to upload your file?
Here is a quick tutorial about how to implement <strike>[WordPress Uploader](http://webomnizz.com/blog/php/how-to-use-wordpress-uploader-into-your-theme/)</strike>

[WordPress Uploader](http://webomnizz.com/how-to-use-wordpress-uploader-into-your-theme/)

Comment: Because it's a custom file type. The uploader won't allow me to upload it.

Comment: @objectiveccoder001 take a look on this link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/file-upload-with-custom-post-type#post-1601832 hope this help you..

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is kinda old, but hopefully will help others.

I was doing something very similar (custom uploads to display on a custom page) and also using practically the exact same code as `objectiveccoder001`. I kept getting "Invalid file." and write permission errors. I ended up going with this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    //var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Works great if you're not looking to use Wordpress's media uploader and just need a simple file upload. It still uploads it using a dated file structure like the built in uploader. Then you can just use `$movefile` array to get the file's data.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: Help full for Custom file uploading

Answer (score 4):

Upload file is very easy in new version of WordPress. Just one line of code:

```
$uploaded_file = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['file']['name'], null, @file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) );
```

**$uploaded_file** is an array which will return all the information including url, file type etc

Answer (score 3):

YOu can use wordpress default media file uploader by using this code and simply retrieve link of image in jquery

```
<label for="upload_image">
        <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="ad_image" value="http://" /> 
        <input id="upload_image_button" class="button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <br />Enter a URL or upload an image
    </label>

<?php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

function my_admin_scripts() {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my-plugin/my-admin.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');
    }
}

?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    var custom_uploader;


    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: true
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            console.log(custom_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON());
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**HOW TO UPLOAD FILES TO A CUSTOM DIRECTORY IN WORDPRESS**

*This example uploads a PDF document in the **wp-content/uploads/customDirectory** folder*

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submittheform">
</form>

global $wp_filesystem;
WP_Filesystem();

$content_directory = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() . 'uploads/';
$wp_filesystem->mkdir( $content_directory . 'CustomDirectory' );

$target_dir_location = $content_directory . 'CustomDirectory/';
 
if(isset($_POST["submittheform"]) && isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
 
    $name_file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 
    if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $target_dir_location.$name_file ) ) {
        echo "File was successfully uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "The file was not uploaded";
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man!
You save my day!