# how to save image in wordpress folder while using custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

**This is my code**

```
 $actual_name = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $original_name = $actual_name;
   $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

> $filetype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
>          $target="../wp-content/themes/childtheme/img/";

```
   if($filetype=='image/jpeg' or $filetype=='image/png' or 
   $filetype=='image/gif')
   {
   $i = 1;
   while(file_exists($target.$actual_name.".".$extension)){       
   $actual_name = $original_name.$i;
   $filename = $actual_name.".".$extension;
   $i++;
   }
   $target = $target.basename( $filename ) ; 
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target);
   $insert="INSERT INTO EnterSchool(SliderImg ) VALUES('".$target."' )";

   if (mysqli_query($db, $insert)) {
   echo "saved ";
   }
   else {
   echo "Error: " . $insert . "" . mysqli_error($db);
   }
   $db->close();
   }}
```

> html

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" >
```

Comment: You should refer https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: @MayankVadiya can we give path like i use in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23836104/5060008

Comment: @MayankVadiya don't understand ..can you please add your answer code with my code